# I could not find step viewer using three.js

Tags: three.js, viewer, cad, step

I want to find a webgl viewer with stp file loader.I could not find any and could not run the ones i found on ubuntu. Three.js does not support stp files i guess. Therefore, it did not work for me. Need some help please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import .step file with three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103516/import-step-file-with-three-js)

Answer (score -1):

You can convert step files to something realtime, using freecad.

Comment: i want to import stp via library. Converting is not my option but thanks.