# how can I view .step files in my JEE web application?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, three.js, 3d, step

I m working on a JEE web application in witch i have to develop a solution to view .step files on the browser.
i tried loading .obj and .fbx files using threejs and it works fine, but there's no loader for .step files in threeJS.
is there any one who know how to get this done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import .step file with three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103516/import-step-file-with-three-js)

Comment: Also related: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/is-there-any-way-to-load-step-file-using-three-js/2842